# Prefinished hardwood floor uneven between head and butt

Tags: hardwood-floor

I have a contractor who installed prefinished hardwood flooring.  When I slide my sock from side to side, it's very smooth.  However, there are some spots when I slide my sock up and down that are uneven.

He says, worst case scenario, he will sand the whole thing down smooth and refinish.

I'm happy he's willing to do that, but seems a little extreme.  Is there anything else he can try to get it smooth?  The floor is already down.

Comment: Can you clarify "side to side" and "up and down" relative to the direction of the individual boards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be, especially since he offered, have the contractor do just that - resand the whole thing. You don't pay for a prefinished hardwood floor expecting to have little bumps and divots in it. Our house has original hardwood floors, that we had refinished a few years ago. After refinishing, they were as smooth as glass, all the way across the room. If you just leave it now, most likely those little uneven spots will nag at you and bother you more and more until a year from now you will have to pay someone to resand the whole floor. Just my 2 cents worth. Hope this helps.